# JWT авторизация angular 7

Tags: angular2, jwt

Подскажите, как лучше работать с данными пользователя при авторизации? Записывать какие-то данные о нем в localStorage и брать оттуда или хранить данные о пользователя в сервисе?

И побочный вопрос. Как на клиенте проверять время истечения токена? У меня пришла идея искать 401 ответы, но мне кажется это что-то не то.

Comment: я б сказал на этот вопрос вы бы нашли миллиард ответов в гугле, тк это жевано-пережевано. На клиенте никто не проверяет время истечения токена,  при формировании токена, сервак подписывает JWT-токен приватным ключом. Токен (подпись) невозможно подделать. Строится на криптографии с открытым ключом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Использовать cookie

С jwt самый простой вариант - это использовать куки. Плюсом куки будет то что можно установить когда они истекут. Соответсвенно решить вопрос их валидации по времени.
Создать на сервере токен, записать на сервере в куку с датой просрочки. Клиенту, в таком случае, вообще ничего не надо делать.

## Использовать sessionStorage

После авторизации записать токен в sessionStorage и пока вкладка будет жить, будет жить и токен. И, конечно, в другой вкладке токена не будет, и, соответсвенно, клиент авторизирован не будет.

## localStorage

localStorage будет хранить токен всегда. Но это провлемой не должно быть. Потому что при **каждом** аякс запросе токен должен **проверятся**. И, соответсвенно, при 401 удаляться, а после авторизации опять перезаписываться.